# How web matrix differ from Visual Studio .is it more efficient than Visual Studio to develop ASP.NET Web Project?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio

WebMatrix is a web development and deployment tool by Microsoft so how
is this compared to Visual Studio? which Use **C# Razor Syntax** is that more better coding.

***Razor Syntax**-*

```
Combining Text and markup   

@foreach(var item in items) {
  <span>@item.Prop</span> 
}

Razor Delegate
    @{
      Func<dynamic, object> b = 
       @<strong>@item</strong>;
    }
    @b("Bold this")
```

Comment: VS 2010 SP1 fully supports Razor.

Comment: @SLaks - **Only** later versions of Visual Studio support Razor and even then only when the Service Packs are installed.

Comment: Which is better User For Develop ASP.NET Web Project.....

Comment: Why do you assume that one is better than the other, in general. One may be better than the other in particular circumstances. What are your circumstances? Professional? Hobby? School?

Answer (score 2):

If you're just starting out I would definitely opt for Visual Studio or Visual Web Developer over WebMatrix. Intellisense works better in Visual Studio, and I find it easier to work with in general. WebMatrix is a good product, but I would stick to Visual Studio.

If you can afford it, I would grab the full version of Visual Studio 2010. There are a lot of extra features, and there's a lot more you can do with the full version. The express editions are good for basic stuff, but they're limited.

That's my two cents. Hope it helps.

Comment: Agreed. Visual Web Developer has the features you'll need when you're starting out, but the most annoying limitation (in my experience) is that VWD can't load VS plugins, so things like ReSharper don't work.  If you can swing it, definitely pick up VS2010.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on who you ask.  If you are just getting started and want to develop using Razor pages then I think WebMatrix is going to be a little easier to get started.  Visual Web Developer SP1 will let you build sites with Razor Pages also.  If can edit ASP .NET MVC and ASP .NET Web projects with WebMatrix, but you cannot create those types of projects.  For those types you will need Visual Studio or Visual Studio Web Developer.

There are several prominent (IMO) developers that use WebMatrix and Razor pages.  You can check out what they say here:

http://wekeroad.com/microsoft/someone-hit-their-head

http://wekeroad.com/microsoft/the-super-dynamic-massive-freakshow

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/CommentView.aspx?guid=d6043642-fccc-45c5-85d3-79616a346fd4

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HanseminutesPodcast249OnWebMatrixWithRobConery.aspx

Hope this helps.